# AVFoundation: Creating an AVAsset from NSData Without Saving to Device. Is it possible?

Tags: swift2, avfoundation

In my app a video is recorded by the user. When the user finishes recording, the video is then compressed using a compression algorithm which returns the video as NSData. I am then writing the data to a file and saving it to my server.

I am retrieving the saved videos and displaying them on a `tableView`. In theory there could be dozens of videos on the feed.

When I retrieve a video from the server and decompress it, I am stuck with an NSData object.

I am looking for help turning this object into an `AVAsset` without saving the file to the device.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: you don't need to save it to a file, you can directly convert NSData to AVAsset, but then you would need to keep the assets in ram and if you have  a dozen if them then you might run into memory issues. so it would be best to keep them in a file and convert them to AVAsset if needed

Comment: Ive been struggling trying to convert the NSData object into an AVAsset.. If you wouldn't mind, could you give me an example of how you would do that?

Comment: I would like a solution for this too. That way I can use App Slicing from Asset Catalogs on video files. Otherwise this would lose the point to do it, if I had to write temporary files from Asset Catalog data. Since Asset Catalog data is accessed over `NSDataAsset`, I see no way to get URL from it.

Answer (score 0):

I extended `NSDataAsset` to conform to `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` protocol and I extended `AVURLAsset` to init using a `NSDataAsset`.

You can find my solution in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69298570/15042552